# Tables as PDF images

Tags: tables, floats

Due to time constraints I'm considering cheating a little and importing some tables I've created in Excel into my latex document. I realise I can do this quite nicely as a 'figure' using something like the following,

```
\begin{figure} [t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,scale=1]{abc}
\caption{Plot of Testing Time Frame vs Gross Profit/.Total Commission.}
\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

However, obviously this is now recognised as a figure... and appears in my list of figures rather than my list of tables.

Question, is there a way of doing this but for the PDF image imported to be recognised and labelled as a table?

Comment: `\begin{table}` instead of `figure` should do the trick.

Comment: Just a comment: I'm a graphical editor of a journal, and I'm very angry when authors do this. At least get the correct font in your Excel. In the case of "default font" Computer Modern or Latin Modern, [you can get the font files here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm)

Comment: Another comment: the options `[width=\textwidth,scale=1]` are surely fighting and one of them does not take effect.

Comment: Maybe your better off using this tool: [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/). i think its also faster to use this than export images from excel and then try to import them to latex.

Comment: Good ideas thank you. I have just tried importing a table from excel2latex and I get an error on \toprule saying undefined control sequence... any ideas? Do I need to install a package?

Comment: Either use the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package or uncheck the "Booktabs-style formatting" checkbox in the export dialog of excel2latex.

Comment: @jrast: you could probably turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 22):

Use `table` instead of `figure`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{exceltable}
\caption{This is an excel table.}
\label{tab:ExcelTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- Adjust the `width` until it suits your preferences.
- The table example is taken from [this site](http://www.oakfurniturehouse.co.uk/userfiles/image/3B4K1820.jpg).

Comment: very classy! -- an oak table, indeed...

Answer (score 10):

It's better to export the table as latex source than an image. By using the [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) tool, this is a very easy task.

To include the exported table you have to include the following packages to your main tex file: [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/), [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/)

```
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
```

If you don't want to use the booktabs package, you can uncheck the "Booktabs-style formatting" chechkbox in the export dialog. [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/) are used as soon as you have merged cells in your excel sheet. If you don't see any `\multicol` or `\multirow`command in your exported table, you don't have to include these packages.