# Table errors with excel2latex

Tags: tables

Following [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69565/16873), I have just converted a table using [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/), and I get the following output from it,

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrcccccc}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{VC-A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{VC-B} &     \multicolumn{2}{c}{Difference (\%)} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Patterns} & Average Iterations & Maximum  Iterations & Average Iterations & Maximum  Iterations & Average & Maximum \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{Bullish}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 29.29 & 70    & 26.30 & 30    & 11.37 & 133 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 29.11 & 76    & 25.58 & 30    & 13.80 & 153 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & 32.91 & 75    & 27.52 & 30    & 19.59 & 150 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & 33.65 & 76    & 28.16 & 30    & 19.50 & 153 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{Bearish}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 29.42 & 73    & 26.26 & 30    & 12.03 & 143 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 28.98 & 73    & 25.49 & 30    & 13.69 & 143 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & 32.92 & 80    & 27.47 & 30    & 19.84 & 167 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & 33.71 & 80    & 28.09 & 30    & 20.01 & 167 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I have the `bookends` and `array` packages installed. I get an error saying

```
! Undefined control sequence.\@sharp ->\multirow{4}[8]{}{Bullish} ...column{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{}{Bullish}}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the follwing packages: [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/), [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/):

```
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
```

If you dont't want to use the booktabs package, uncheck the "Booktabs-style formatting" checkbox in the export dialog of excel2latex.

Comment: Thanks. If I turn off "Booktabs-style formatting" I get a different error... this time on the new line "\cline{3-8}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{VC-A} &" I get the usual undefined control sequence... do I need different packages?

Comment: @RobD Please, make a complete M(N)WE. It is difficult to see what is producing the error without.

Comment: even if you turn off "Booktabs-style formatting" you still need to include the multicol and the multirow package.