# How to plot a data from excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: pgfplots

I am really new in latex.
I have a data from excel file, which contains different sheet.
I need to plot these data on latex, any one have an idea?? I need it urgently please.

Comment: I have to include at least 4~5 curves in each plot. I measn 2-y-axis.

Comment: You'll need to export the sheets to individual `.csv` files, and then you can plot them using [tag:pgfplots].

Comment: For an urgently needed solution try saving the plots from Excel as images and including them in your document with `includegraphics`. This isn't elegant, but it will be faster than learning the LaTeX to do it in LaTeX.

Comment: I've heard that there is a tool called `excel2latex`, which exports excel data into latex tables. Perhaps this post can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69648/16873

Comment: @user18307: Use pgfplots. For details read run `texdoc pgfplots` from command prompt.